# Animating Custom UITableViewCells to the left in editing mode (instead of right)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cells and I'd like the user to be able to move cells around. The problem is that when the tableview goes into editing mode, the cells move to the right like this

[image]

But I want them to move to the left, so the cells aren't blocked by the reordering control

I've looked at a bunch of SO questions but I haven't found any answers. Is there a simple way to do this, or will I have to write the animation myself?

Also, can someone tell me why this is happening?

NOTE

This is the delegate method I added to do this

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return YES;
}
```

And, yes, I did add the custom views to the custom cells content views

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the setEditing:animated: function of the UITableViewCell to create a custom animation and move the controls in the direction you need.

For example

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (animated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            CGRect titleFrame = self.titleLabel.frame;

            if (editing) {
                [self.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(15, titleFrame.origin.y, titleFrame.size.width, titleFrame.size.height)];
            } else {
                [self.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(25, titleFrame.origin.y, titleFrame.size.width, titleFrame.size.height)];

            }
        }completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that. The UI looked good but the reorder control didn't work

Comment: Yes. It actually disappears your way

Comment: You did call super right? [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

Comment: Yes. I was able to figure it out thanks to your help with the `setEditing:editing` method though. Thanks!